# Julia best way to reshape multi-dim array

Tags: dataframe, reshape, julia

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
julia> sim1.value[1:5,:,:]
5x3x3 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  0.201974   0.881742  0.497407
  0.0751914  0.921308  0.732588
 -0.109084   1.06304   1.15962 
 -0.0149133  0.896267  1.22897 
  0.717094   0.72558   0.456043

[:, :, 2] =
  1.28742  0.760712  1.61112
  2.21436  0.229947  1.87528
 -1.66456  1.46374   1.94794
 -2.4864   1.84093   2.34668
 -2.79278  1.61191   2.22896

[:, :, 3] =
 0.649675  0.899028  0.628103
 0.718837  0.665043  0.153844
 0.914646  0.807048  0.207743
 0.612839  0.790611  0.293676
 0.759457  0.758115  0.280334
```

I have names for the 2nd dimension in

```
julia> sim1.names
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "beta[1]"
 "beta[2]"
 "s2"
```

Whats best way to reshape this multi-dim array so that I have a data frame like:

```
 beta[1]  | beta[2]   | s2       | chain
 0.201974 |  0.881742 | 0.497407 |   1
 0.0751914|  0.921308 | 0.732588 |   1
-0.109084 |  1.06304  | 1.15962  |   1
-0.0149133|  0.896267 | 1.22897  |   1
 ...      |  ...      | ...      |   ...
 1.28742  |  0.760712 | 1.61112  |   2
 2.21436  |  0.229947 | 1.87528  |   2
-1.66456  |  1.46374  | 1.94794  |   2
-2.4864   |  1.84093  | 2.34668  |   2
-2.79278  |  1.61191  | 2.22896  |   2
 ...      |  ...      | ...      |   ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, I think the best way to do this would be a mixture of loops and calls to `reshape`:

```
using DataFrames
A = randn(5, 3, 3)

df = DataFrame()
for j in 1:3
  df[j] = reshape(A[:, :, j], 5 * 3)
end

names!(df, [:beta1, :beta2, :s2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data, it seems you wanted to basically stack the three matrices output by `sim1.value[1:5,:,:]` on top of each other vertically, plus add another column with the index of the matrix. The accepted answer of the brilliant and venerable John Myles White seems to put the entire contents of each of those matrices into it's own column.

The below matches your desired output using `vcat` for the stacking and `hcat` and `fill` to add the extra column. JMW I'm sure will know if there's a better way :)

```
using DataFrames
A = randn(5, 3, 3)
names = ["beta[1]","beta[2]","s2"]

push!(names, "chain")
newA = vcat([hcat(A[:,:,i],fill(i,size(A,1))) for i in 1:size(A,3)]...)
df = DataFrame(newA, Symbol[names...])
```

note also you can do this slightly more concisely without the explicit calls to hcat and vcat:

```
newA = [[[A[:,:,i] fill(i,size(A,1))] for i in 1:size(A,3)]...]
```